# Printing pattern sequence of 3 characters

Tags: php

I would like to print pattern of 3 characters using PHP. Like aaa, aab, aac .... zzz.

Now, I am using these PHP code but it is printing randomly instead sequence.

```
$i = 1; 
$chars = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z");

while($i > 0){ $current = $chars[rand(0,25)].$chars[rand(0,25)].$chars[rand(0,25)]; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick but sloppy

```
$i=0;
$j=0;
$k=0;
while($i<26){
  while($j<26){
    while($k<26){
      echo $chars[$i] . $chars[$j] . $chars[$k];
      $k++;
    }
    $j++;
    $k=0;
  }
  $i++;
  $j=0;
  $k=0;
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\start\test2.php on line 12

Comment: But when i replace "echo chars[$i] . chars[$j] . chars[$k];" with "echo "hi <br />";" Then printing hi.

Comment: @RinkuYadav ok try that then, see if that fixes anything:
echo "chars[$i] chars[$j] chars[$k] <br/>";

Comment: @RinkuYadav oops just realized it, forgot the '$' in front of the chars

Comment: Yes it's printing right sequence of array but when i use echo chars[$i] . chars[$j] . chars[$k]; then it display error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in. can i print characters instead array ?

Comment: @RinkuYadav I updated my answer you need the '$' in front of the variable: echo $chars[$i] . $chars[$j] . $chars[$k];

Comment: @RinkuYadav copy and paste my new answer see if it gives you error, you keep showing me my old answer

Comment: Yeah, i was also forget $ before variable. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Count from 0 to 26^3 -1. Then convert your numbers to base 26 , replace numbers by letters as needed, and prefix with "a" or "aa" if the converted result is single or double digit.

Use this function: string base_convert ( string $number , int $frombase , int $tobase )

I am not going to code it all out for you. You need to learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it in c#.

```
        string sample = "AAA";
        char[] chars = sample.ToCharArray();

        char first = chars[0];
        char second = chars[1];
        char third = chars[2];

        if (first == second && first == third)
        {
            third++;
            bool isAlphaBet = Regex.IsMatch(third.ToString(), "[a-z]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (isAlphaBet)
            {
                return $"{first}{second}{third}";
            }
            return $"empty";
        }
        if (first == second && first != third)
        {
            third++;
            bool isAlphaBet = Regex.IsMatch(third.ToString(), "[a-z]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (isAlphaBet)
            {
                return $"{first}{second}{third}";
            }
            else
            {
                second++;
                third = 'A';

                return $"{first}{second}{third}";
            }
        }//"ABA";
        if (first != second && first == third)
        {
            third++;

            bool isAlphaBet = Regex.IsMatch(third.ToString(), "[a-z]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (isAlphaBet)
            {
                return $"{first}{second}{third}";
            }
            else
            {
                second++;
                third = 'A';

                return $"{first}{second}{third}";
            }
           
        }
        if (first != second && first != third && second != third)
        {
            third++;

            bool isAlphaBet = Regex.IsMatch(third.ToString(), "[a-z]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (isAlphaBet)
            {
                return $"{first}{second}{third}";
            }
            else
            {
                second++;
                third = 'A';
                bool isAlphaBetSecond = Regex.IsMatch(second.ToString(), "[a-z]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                if (isAlphaBetSecond)
                {
                    return $"{first}{second}{third}";
                }
                else
                {
                    second = 'A';
                    first++;
                    bool isAlphaBetFirst = Regex.IsMatch(first.ToString(), "[a-z]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    if (isAlphaBetFirst)
                    {
                        return $"{first}{second}{third}";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return $"empty";
                    }
                }
              
            }

        }
        if (first != second && second == third)
        {
            third++;
            bool isAlphaBetThird = Regex.IsMatch(third.ToString(), "[a-z]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (isAlphaBetThird)
            {
                return $"{first}{second}{third}";
            }
            else
            {
                third = 'A';
                second++;
                bool isAlphaBetSecond = Regex.IsMatch(second.ToString(), "[a-z]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                if (isAlphaBetSecond)
                {
                    return $"{first}{second}{third}";
                }
                else
                {
                    second = 'A';
                    first++;
                    bool isAlphaBetFirst = Regex.IsMatch(first.ToString(), "[a-z]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    if (isAlphaBetFirst)
                    {
                        return $"{first}{second}{third}";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return $"empty";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $"{first}{second}{third}";
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to print random - like 'aaa' or 'vvv' or 'ddd' - try to use

```
$char = $chars[rand(0,25)]; 
echo $current = $char.$char.$char;
```

If you want to print 'aaa','bbb','ccc',...- use

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 26; $i++) {
    $char = $chars[$i]; 
    echo $current = $char.$char.$char;
}
```

Comment: I need sequence instead random. please read question once again.